# kotlin coroutines with suspend lambda

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following class that uses a builder pattern for the onFailure and onSuccess

```
sealed interface APIResponse<T>  {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T) : APIResponse<T>
    data class Failure<Nothing>(val error: Exception) : APIResponse<Nothing>

    suspend fun onSuccess(block: suspend (data: T) -> Unit): APIResponse<T> {
        if (this is Success) {
            block(data)
        }
        return this
    }

    suspend fun onFailure(block: suspend (error: Exception) -> Unit): APIResponse<T> {
        if (this is Failure) {
            block(error)
        }
        return this
    }
}
```

I have use the suspend modifier on the lamda so I can use it like this in this class as the saveUserToken is a suspend function.

```
class UserTokenRepositoryImp(
    private val userTokenLocalDataSource: UserTokenLocalDataSource,
    private val userTokenRemoteDataSource: UserTokenRemoteDataSource) : UserTokenRepository {

    override suspend fun requestToken(userTokenRequestModel: UserTokenRequestModel): APIResponse<UserTokenModel> {
        return userTokenRemoteDataSource.requestToken(userTokenRequestModel.toUserTokenRequestDto())
            .onSuccess { userTokenDto ->
                saveUserToken(userToken = userTokenDto.accessToken)
            }
            .onFailure { exception ->
                // Log error
            }
    }

    override suspend fun saveUserToken(userToken: String) {
        userTokenLocalDataSource.saveUserToken(userToken)
    }

    override suspend fun fetchUserToken(): String? {
        return userTokenLocalDataSource.fetchUserToken()
    }
}
```

Just wondering if this is good practice as the onSuccess is a suspend function and the lambda is also a suspend function.

Comment: I don't see how double bagging helps.  Is the lambda called outside the context of the suspend function, for another reason?  In that case you might want the lambda to suspend, but I doubt it.    Once a lambda is started, I don't want it to suspend.  I want it to finish.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. If saveUserToken() is suspend then it does make sense.

Comment: Soliciting opinions on "best practices" is considered off topic.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing/142354#142354

Comment: The Failure class should just be declared `Failure`, not `Failure<Nothing>`, which is introducing a redundant type named `Nothing` and shadowing the actual Nothing type, that you are passing along as the `T` of the interface.

Comment: Seeing onSuccess and onFailure in a suspend function intuitively makes me cringe because it appears like the asynchronous pattern even though you are eventually calling them synchronously within the coroutine. Very confusing. Most coroutine APIs like Retrofit and Firebase use straightforward suspend functions that return a sealed type like you’ve already prepared, or return the result on success and throw on failure.

Comment: Regard my first comment, the interface needs to use `out T` for Failure to be able to avoid needing a generic type like this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem only arises because you introduce a level of indirection that isn't needed.

Just replace your `requestToken` function by this:

```
override suspend fun requestToken(userTokenRequestModel: UserTokenRequestModel): APIResponse<UserTokenModel> =
    userTokenRemoteDataSource.requestToken(userTokenRequestModel.toUserTokenRequestDto()).apply {
        when (this) {
            is APIResponse.Success -> saveUserToken(userToken = data.accessToken)
            is APIResponse.Failure -> println(error.message) // Log error
        }
    }
```

Now you can remove the methods from the interface. It was confusing anyways why there was an `onSuccess` method on the type `Failure` (and vice versa).

The code is shorter, better to understand (no more indirections) and since you do not pass lambdas around anymore you won't have a problem with properly calling them in a coroutine scope.

And while we are at it, `APIResponse` and `APIResponse.Success` both have a type parameter `T`. You should rename one so they cannot be so easily confused with one another. After all, they are completely different and independent type parameters.

Comment: Disagree about avoiding Success using the name T since it’s directly passing it along to be the same thing as the super’s T, so it is effectively the same thing. I’ve never seen anyone do what you’re suggesting with generics in Java or Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this dilemma by making `onSuccess` and `onFailure` into `inline` functions.

The `APIResponse` interface won't be able to contain public inline functions, so we'll have to turn them into extension functions instead.

```kotlin
sealed interface APIResponse<T> {
  data class Success<T>(val data: T) : APIResponse<T>
  data class Failure<Nothing>(val error: Exception) : APIResponse<Nothing>
}

inline fun <T> APIResponse<T>.onSuccess(block: (data: T) -> Unit): APIResponse<T> {
  if (this is APIResponse.Success) {
    block(data)
  }
  return this
}

inline fun <T> APIResponse<T>.onFailure(block: (error: Exception) -> Unit): APIResponse<T> {
  if (this is APIResponse.Failure) {
    block(error)
  }
  return this
}
```

Now you can call `onSuccess` and `onFailure` from anywhere. You don't need the `suspend` modifier, but you will be able to include suspending calls in the lambda `block` when `onSuccess`/`onFailure` is called from a suspending function.

```kotlin
suspend fun foo() = response.onSuccess { delay(100) } // works fine

fun bar() = response.onSuccess { println("Hello!") } // also fine
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is similar to my [ConcurrentActionHandler class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authsamples/basicmobileapp/plumbing/utilities/ConcurrentActionHandler.kt), which I initially struggled to get working the way I wanted.

With Kotlin you can't just await an async callback parameter and you need to create a new coroutine. So update your code like this and I think it will work as you expect.

```kotlin
suspend fun onSuccess(block: suspend (data: T) -> Unit): APIResponse<T> {

    that = this@ApiResponse<T>;
    return suspendCoroutine { continuation -> {
  
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {

            if (that is Success) {
                block(data)
            }
            return it.resume(that)
        }
    }
}
```

Out of interest my particular use case is synchronizing OAuth token refresh for multiple UI views that call APIs concurrently.

Here is the same code in a couple of other languages. The JavaScript syntax is most intuitive I think, and originally I expected Kotlin to work in the same way.

- [TypeScript](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/utilities/concurrentActionHandler.ts)
- [Swift](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Plumbing/Utilities/ConcurrentActionHandler.swift)